# What is the algorithm applied by ImageAdjust[image,{c,b,gamma}]

Tags: image-processing, implementation-details, computer-vision

I want to know how ImageAdjust work to change the pixel values by specifying all parameters b,c and gamma.
In openCV, the transformation is linear `g(x)=alpha*f(x)+beta` where `alhpa` controls the `contrast` and `beta` controls the `brightness` with alpha>0. When I apply this function with an exemple, it does not fit .

```
imageoriginal={{0.492279, 0.413776}, {0.17979, 0.510059}}

ImageAdjust[imageoriginal,{1.,.5}]={{0.976837, 0.741327}, {0.0393686, 1.}}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is stated in the documentation (third example in *Properties & Relations*)

> ImageAdjust[image,{c,b,γ}] is equivalent to ImageApply[Clip[(b+1)(c+1)#^γ - c/2, {0, 1}]&, image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider these examples:

```
ref = N @ Subdivide @ 255;
img = ref~Partition~10 // Image;

ImageAdjust[img, {1, 0, 1}];
ListLinePlot[{Flatten @ ImageData @ %, ref}]

ImageAdjust[img, {0, 1, 1}];
ListLinePlot[{Flatten @ ImageData @ %, ref}]

ImageAdjust[img, {0, 0, 2}];
ListLinePlot[{Flatten @ ImageData @ %, ref}]
```

[image]